# Dockerfile scrapy unknown command: crawl

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, scrapy

Hello i'm trying to run a CMD of my scrapy spider with the Dockerfile. I had set the path to the folder that contain scrapy scrapy.cfg folder and the CMD scrapy crawl estate to start the spider

When i run docker-compose up it return with the error

```
Scrapy 1.5.0 - no active project
web_1        |
web_1        | Unknown command: crawl
web_1        |
web_1        | Use "scrapy" to see available commands
```

Here is my Dockefile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.6-onbuild
RUN  apt-get update &&apt-get upgrade -y&& apt-get install python-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install scrapy
ADD . /scrapy_estate/tutorial
WORKDIR /scrapy_estate/tutorial
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD scrapy crawl estate
```

My directory tree

```
spider
├── CreateDB.sql
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── initdb
│   └── init.sql
├── init.sql
├── npm-debug.log
├── requirements.txt
└── scrapy_estate
    └── tutorial
        ├── scrapy.cfg
        └── tutorial
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── items.py
            ├── middlewares.py
            ├── pipelines.py
            ├── __pycache__
            │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
            │   ├── items.cpython-36.pyc
            │   ├── middlewares.cpython-36.pyc
            │   ├── pipelines.cpython-36.pyc
            │   └── settings.cpython-36.pyc
            ├── settings.py
            └── spiders
                ├── __init__.py
                ├── __pycache__
                │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
                │   └── real_estate_spider.cpython-36.pyc
                └── real_estate_spider.py
```

Did i put the WORKDIR wrong or my CMD is wrong ?
Any help would be appreciate thank you

EDIT:

My serivce ls

```
2to3             __pycache__         docker-compose.yml.save  init.sql        
pip           pydoc3.6        python3.6          requirements.txt   tkconch
2to3-3.6         automat-visualize   easy_install             initdb          
pip3          pyhtmlizer      python3.6-config   scrapy             trial
CreateDB.sql     cftp                easy_install-3.6         items.py        
pip3.6        python          python3.6m         scrapy_estate  twist
Dockerfile       ckeygen             idle                     mailmail        
pipelines.py  python-config   python3.6m-config  settings.py        twistd
Dockerfile.save  conch               idle3                    middlewares.py  
pydoc         python3         pyvenv             spiders            wheel
__init__.py      docker-compose.yml  idle3.6                  npm-debug.log   
pydoc3        python3-config  pyvenv-3.6         splash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CMD ["scrapy", "crawl", "estate"]
```

If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the  will execute in `/bin/sh -c`:

If you want to run your  without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the executable. This array form is the preferred format of CMD. Any additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the array:

```
FROM python:3.6-onbuild
RUN  apt-get update &&apt-get upgrade -y&& apt-get install python-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install scrapy
ADD . /scrapy_estate/tutorial
WORKDIR /scrapy_estate/tutorial
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD scrapy crawl estate
```

Comment: Actually looks like your docker file is wrong. Try this

Comment: Updated the Answer.

Comment: i removed "COPY .." from Dockerfile and still got " Scrapy 1.5.0 - no active project
web_1        |
web_1        | Unknown command: crawl
web_1        |
web_1        | Use "scrapy" to see available commands
"

Comment: what happens when you just run docker-compose run {whatever_the_service_is} bash and `ls` the directory?

Also does it work in the container directly?

Comment: it seem to only map to scrapy_estate instead of scrapy_estate/tutorial which is the place that can run the scrapy crawl command